# How should I repair these loose tiles in the bathroom?

Tags: tile, crack

I was looking at replacing some caulking that has been cracking and I noticed there's a few loose tiles.

Here's a pic of the bathroom, it's on the second floor of our house:
[image: Bathroom]

Here's where I noticed the tiles, there's also a hairline crack on one near the toilet:
[image: Area]

The grout highlighted here seems to be loose and the tiles wiggle just a little bit. There's also a (possibly unrelated) hairline crack in one by the toilet:
[image: Highlighted]

The surrounding tiles otherwise seem okay.

We replaced our toilet about a year and a half ago and the caulking didn't hold very well and is admittedly overdue for being replaced. That said, I think there always has been a creak in that spot.

How should I go about repairing this? What warning signs do I need to look for?

**Update**: I guess whatever the substrate is was cracked and the wood is damaged. Not sure how to lay something solid down to put the tiles on.

[image: Floor]

[image: Removed Tile]

Comment: A creak seems to imply that the floor moves, and you're going to have a fun time getting tiles to stay stuck to a moving floor ...

Comment: What kind of Underlayment or sub floor art the tiles attached to. With a cement backer board repair may not be hard other than trying to match the grout. If the floor is a wood product this may be much tougher once the wood gets wet and swells (especially with particle board / OSB type products) it can be tough to dry out and re set the tiles. In both cases I would probably use a Mastic or latex adhesive because of the flexing.

Comment: @Ed Beal You would recommend mastic when you feel moisture may be a problem? Not a polymer modified mortar?

Comment: I have had better luck with mastic in areas that flex mortar tends to release easier in my experience.

Comment: @EdBeal I wholeheartedly agree that mastic has superior flexibility, but it's water soluble, and organic matter.

Comment: Late I know, I finally had time to mess with the floor this weekend. I guess they were laid on wood, I added some more photos.

Comment: The water appears to be seeping from under the wall where your plumbing for your shower is. If there is a leak behind the wall, it would explain why your tiles are popping. Check to see if your floor is level. If the floor is pitched to the back wall, then that could be a red herring.